# Python "IN PLACE" functions

Tags: python, in-place

What's the particular reason that some functions in Python operate "IN PLACE", like `[].sort` and `[].reverse`, while some others like `[].append` not?

Comment: By what definition does `[].append` not work "in place" ?

Comment: Does `append` return a new copy of the list, leaving the old one unmodified?

Comment: help([].sort) _explicitly_ states that sorting happens "in place", but help([].append) doesn't...

Comment: @Matt Ball: Nope. It appends to the existing list and doesn't return anything.

Comment: That's because sorting algorithms are frequently classified as "in-place" and "not-in-place," whereas `[].append` would obviously just modify the existing data structure, unless it's immutable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_sorting

Comment: @Guandalino: But both operate in place. Perhaps it's not spelled out in the documentation on `.append` because the non-in-place version would be called `concat` (and is in fact the `+` operator).

Comment: @Omnifarious: that's basically the point I was making (a rhetorical question).

Comment: @Matt Ball: Your question doesn't make any sense then. All the functions you mention operator 'in place'. They do not create new copies of the data structure they operate on.

Comment: @delnan: but isn't that only because `concat` takes both operands as arguments? If the function was `[].concat`, that would be in-place as well, right?

Comment: @Mat Ball: The `+` operator as applied to lists creates a brand new list containing all the elements of the two lists being added. It does not operator `in place`. And yes, if it were a member function that didn't take two arguments, it would also operate `in place`. The name change would not change the semantics of `append`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm

Comment: @Matt: Now that you mention it, I suppose one *might* call in-place appending `.concat`. Honestly, I'd never even consider using that name for a method that's operating in-place. `append` is tied to modification while `concat` can be both in-place and out-of-place...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to my Programming Python 4th edition:

> By default, pop is equivalent to
>   fetching, and then deleting, the last
>   item at offset −1. With an argument,
>   pop deletes and returns the item at
>   that offset—list.pop(-1) is the same
>   as list.pop(). For in-place change
>   operations like append, insert, del,
>   and pop, no new list is created in
>   memory, so execution is quick
>   (performance may further de- pend upon
>   which end is the “top,” but this in
>   turn depends on Python’s current list
>   implementation, as well as measurement
>   concepts we’ll explore later).

There is actually a whole section devoted to this, but this pretty much answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

"[in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)" refers to a sorting algorithms use of only the memory needed to store the list of items plus some small constant. Append isn't a sorting algorithm and thus "in-place" is not meaningful, or at least wouldn't mean the same thing. You're confusing "in-place" in sorting and whether or not it returns a reference to a new object or a modified version of the same object.

Comment: That's not how "in-place" is used when referring to sorting algorithms, or more generally, algorithms which rearrange arrays/lists.

Comment: Thanks, but I linked to that article in my comment (on the question) half an hour ago. I'm talking about sorting algorithms such as [heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), which is in place, vs. typical implementations of [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).