# Behaviour of .reverse() function in python

Tags: python

I'm coming from an R background and am confused about the following:

Suppose I had "hello" in list format saved in the variable *txt*. Thus

```
 txt=  ['h','e','l','l','o']
```

After some testing, the following works:

```
txt.reverse()
"."join(txt)
```

and produces as expected *olleh*.

However, the following does **not** work:

```
"".join(txt.reverse())
```

It gives an error. I'm curious why that is the case as I thought I can "nest" function calls within function calls?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: You could use `reversed` instead: `"".join(reversed(txt))`.

Comment: @roippi `reversed` *is* in-place. Try `reversed([1,2,3])` on the interpreter, it returns a `listreverseiterator` object which means *no copies are made*. The difference is that `.reverse()` modifies the original list, while `reversed()` iterates over it.

Comment: @Bakuriu yep.  Haven't had my coffee today.  "in place" (or the inverse) is a bad description for any sort of iterator.

Comment: @Bakuriu That just means `reversed` returns an iterator that will return the items in reverse order. It does not modify the original argument, which the `reverse` method does.

Comment: @chepner It depends on what you define by "in-place". My definition is "an operation that uses `O(1)` memory", which is the algorithmic definition. I believe to express the other meaning it would be better to speak of *side-effects* or of *copies*, which is more explicit than "in-place". For example `sequence.sort()` is in-place, meaning that it has side-effects, but not in-place, meaning that it takes `O(1)` memory. Better differentiate between the two.

Comment: As a side note, if you were only storing the string in a list to reverse it, a better idea is to simply reverse the string as-is: `a = "hello"; b = a[::-1]; print b # 'olleh'`.  For an explanation of that check out slice notation in python. (You can also do that on your list... `"".join(txt[::-1])`)

Comment: What does the `in place`means?

Comment: @viddhart - Here is an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317817/python-in-place-functions

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the `reverse()` function does *not* return an useful value (it returns `None`), because it reverses the list in-place, as a way to avoid the need to create a new output list. So this:

```
"".join(txt.reverse())
```

... Will try to join `None`, which clearly will fail.

Answer (score 5):

Being an in-place function, the `reverse` method of a list *always* returns `None`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> print a.reverse()
None
>>> a
[2, 1]
>>>
```

You can get the behavior you want by using the [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reversed) built-in:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b']
>>> "".join(reversed(a))
'ba'
>>> a
['a', 'b']
>>>
```

Comment: Maybe also show the unmodified value of `a` in the `reversed` example, as you did the modified value of `a` in the `reverse` one?

Comment: Awesome, this is EXACTLY what was confusing me. In R, it's pretty much always an object that's returned, so I never had to worry about it. Makes complete sense. Thank you again.

Comment: @user1357015 In python operations that have side-effects usually do *not* return a value(i.e. they return `None`). Conversely, functions that return a value usually do *not* have side-effects. It's a convention used pretty often. By the way: you can always obtain R behaviour using some `or`s: `"".join(txt.reverse() or txt)`. `txt.reverse()` returns `None`, which is considered false, so python will evaluate `txt` and return it instead(return values of `or` and `and` need *not* be booleans). However this seems quite dirty.

Answer (score 3):

your problem is that `txt.reverse()` does NOT return the reversed list, it returns `None`,

ie, `txt.reverse()` reverses your list in place

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reversed` instead:

```
".".join(reversed(txt))
```

Answer (score 1):

As already said the `list.reverse()` replaces the list in-place, thus returns `None`

If you want a nestable version you can use the `reversed` function

```
In [7]: "".join(reversed(txt))
Out[7]: 'olleh'
```