# How to remove '\n' from end of strings inside a list?

Tags: python

I have 2 strings here:

```
line= ['ABDFDSFGSGA', '32\n']
line= ['NBMVA\n']
```

How do I remove `\n` from the end of these strings. I've tried `rstrip()` and `strip()` but I am still unable to remove the `\n` from the string. Can I have help removing it?

Comment: Show us the actual code you've tried. You're on the right path...

Comment: try again `map(str.rstrip, line)` give me `['ABDFDSFGSGA', '32']`

Comment: Hint: You don't have strings, but list of strings.

Comment: i have tried line.remove('\n') as well as line.rstrip('\n') also line.strip()

Comment: Thanks, but please edit it into the question, then we can all see what doesn't work :)

Comment: @devnull I don't agree - he is aware of `rstrip`

Comment: @SteinarLima ok, then it would a dup of an elementary list comprehension question.

Comment: @devnull Or problem with understanding in-place and not in-place methods. I can't find a suitable dup, but if you can, please let us know.

Comment: @SteinarLima [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849509/python-how-to-remove-n-from-a-list-element/) is an exact dup.

Answer (score 14):

You need to access the element that you want to strip from the list:

```
line= ['ABDFDSFGSGA', '32\n']

#We want to strip all elements in this list
stripped_line = [s.rstrip() for s in line]
```

What you might have done wrong, is to simply call `line[1].rstrip()`. This won't work, since the `rstrip` method does not work [inplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317817/python-in-place-functions), but returns a new string which is stripped.

Example:

```
>>> a = 'mystring\n'
>>> a.rstrip()
Out[22]: 'mystring'
>>> a
Out[23]: 'mystring\n'
>>> b = a.rstrip()
>>> b
Out[25]: 'mystring'
```

Answer (score 6):

The type of line is list, so you cannot apply any of the `strip` methods. The strip methods is for strings.

There you need to iterate over the list and apply `rstrip()` method on each string present in that list.

```
>>> line= ['ABDFDSFGSGA', '32\n']
>>> map(str.rstrip, line)
['ABDFDSFGSGA', '32']
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `.replace('\n','')` but just note that this will delete all instances of `\n` If you want to do this for entire list you could just do:

```
line = [i.replace('\n','') for i in line]
```

Comment: No downvote, but this will remove `\n` in the middle of the strings as well, if `line` is a string.

Comment: This will do nothing to a list... `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't look carefully. I edited my answer to work for a list.

Comment: No worries :). It was a sneaky one!

Comment: OP states that he want to remove `\n` from the end of the strings, so this I'm not sure if this answer suits this question.

Comment: Maybe your right, but the question can be interpreted in a way that OP was just pointing out that the `\n`s were at the end of the strings and didn't explicitly state to only remove those `\n`