# stripping \n from every element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am currently completely new to python and trying to build a simple hangman game. I created a .txt file with all the sample words and imported it to python. When printing them out however they all have this format: ['exampleword\n'], ['exampleword2\n'] I however want to get rid of the \n ending. I tried most of the suggestions from this thread: [How to remove '\n' from end of strings inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325212/how-to-remove-n-from-end-of-strings-inside-a-list), but they didn't work.

```
woerter = open("woerter.txt", "r")
wortliste = [line.split("\t") for line in woerter.readlines()]
print(wortliste)
```

I have python 3.8.2. installed, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: try `[line.split("\n\t") for line in woerter.readlines()]`

Comment: looks like all are in that format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
woerter = open("woerter.txt", "r")
wortliste = [line.rstrip() for line in woerter.readlines()]
print(wortliste)
```

Answer (score 0):

no reason to use `readlines`, you can just iterate over the file directly:

```
with open('woerter.txt') as f:
    wortlist = [l.strip() for l in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.splitlines()`.
for example:

```py
string = "this\n"
string += "has\n"
string += "multiple\n"
string += "lines"

words = string.splitlines()
print(words)

# Outputs: ['this', 'has', 'multiple', 'lines']
```

```py
with open("woerter.txt", 'r') as f:
    wordlist = f.read().splitlines()
```