# why do the Sort Method Return My Output to None?

Tags: python, list, sorting, methods, append

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(5)
mylist.append(27)
mylist.append(3)
mylist.append(12)
print(mylist)

mylist = mylist.sort()   
print(mylist)
```

I am learning the list methods I run it and it is showing the output None, but I added 5,27,3,12 to my list

```
C:\Users\bendi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject10\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:\Users\bendi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject10\main.py 
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The built-in sort() method of a Python list returns None. It sorts the list *in situ*

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code lies in the line `mylist = mylist.sort()`.

Python's `sort()` method is an [`in-place`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317817/python-in-place-functions); Mean it will return `None`.

This is why you get `None` as the output when you print it.

To fix this, you can remove the assignment statement and just call the `sort()` method on `mylist` directly, like this:

```py
mylist.sort()
print(mylist)
```